# issue with capturing long text-shadow and box-shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas plugin to capture div.

I am actually developing a open source plugin for community where I have one module the user can capture the screen but while capturing its not capturing a text-shadow and box-shadow. I am using long shadow here where in I have multiple values for text-shadow and box-shadow

E.g :

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(1, 107, 179) ,1px 1px 0px rgb(1, 107, 179) ,2px 2px 0px rgb(1, 107, 179) ,3px 3px 0px rgb(1, 107, 179) ,4px 4px 0px rgb(1, 107, 179) ,5px 5px 0px rgb(2, 108, 180) ,6px 6px 0px rgb(2, 108, 180) ,7px 7px 0px rgb(2, 108, 180) ,8px 8px 0px rgb(2, 108, 180) ,9px 9px 0px rgb(3, 109, 181) ..........
```

This is not getting captured ... And also some crazy stuff happening when I give border-radius property.

Here is a JSFiddle you can have a look https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/pn7pLhp6/2/

Or is there any other way than html2canvas to capture the div?

Comment: some stacks say only basic text-shadow is supported.

Comment: I developed that using canvas to svg now its up and running fine... have a look at here https://aminkodaganur.github.io/iconplus/  click download svg from header u will get icon as  svg ... @moeiscool